# Android Spinner equivalent in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In Android, there's a nifty [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) (more or less like a combobox). What is the equivalent in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the print screens of that control it looks like the ListPicker control from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com) is the equivalent of what you're looking for.

Here's a good tutorial of getting started with this control @ http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=230

Comment: Thanks for the link to the toolkit! :)